# Crash when thread is deleted

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, heap-corruption

I am developing an application with MFC.
The UI thread launch a worker thread and stop it when the app is closing. The issue is that the app is crashing each time it tries to delete the thread.

here is the code :

First the thread class and its implementation :

```
class FileThread : public CWinThread
{
public:
    static FileThread* CreateWorkerThread(LPVOID params, UINT priority, UINT flags);

    void InitThread();
    void StopThread();
    inline HANDLE GetStopHandle() const { return m_stopThread; }
    inline HANDLE GetWaitHandle() const { return m_waitThread; }

private:
    HANDLE m_stopThread;
    HANDLE m_waitThread;

    FileThread(): m_stopThread(NULL), m_waitThread(NULL) { }

    static UINT MyThreadProc(LPVOID pParam);
};

FileThread* FileThread::CreateWorkerThread(LPVOID params, UINT priority, UINT flags)
{
    return (FileThread*) AfxBeginThread(FileThread::MyThreadProc, params, priority, 0,  flags);
}

void FileThread::InitThread()
{
    m_stopThread = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
    m_waitThread = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
}

void FileThread::StopThread()
{
    ::SetEvent(m_stopThread);
    ::WaitForSingleObject(m_waitThread, INFINITE);
    ::CloseHandle(m_stopThread);
    ::CloseHandle(m_waitThread);
}


UINT FileThread::MyThreadProc(LPVOID pParam)
{
    ThreadData* pLink = (ThreadData*)pParam;
    BOOL continueProcess = TRUE;
    int returnCode = EXITCODE_SUCCESS;

    while (continueProcess)
    {
        if(::WaitForSingleObject(pLink->pMe->GetStopHandle(), 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            ::SetEvent(pLink->pMe->GetWaitHandle());
            continueProcess = FALSE;
        }

        // the thread is looking for some files...
    }

    delete pLink; // it was allocated from the UI thread

    return returnCode;
}
```

Then, where I start the thread:

```
ThreadData * td = new ThreadData();

m_myFileThread = FileThread::CreateWorkerThread((LPVOID)td, THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST, CREATE_SUSPENDED);

td->pMe = m_myFileThread;
m_myFileThread->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;

m_myFileThread->InitThread();
m_myFileThread->ResumeThread();
```

Finally, the stop (and the crash):

```
DWORD exitCode;
if (m_myFileThread != NULL && GetExitCodeThread(m_myFileThread->m_hThread, &exitCode) && (exitCode == STILL_ACTIVE))
    {
        m_myFileThread->StopThread();
        if(::WaitForSingleObject(m_myFileThread->m_hThread, 5000) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
        {
            TerminateThread(m_myFileThread->m_hThread, EXITCODE_ABORT);
        }
    }

if (m_myFileThread != NULL)
{ 
    delete m_myFileThread; // => CRASH
}
```

It seems I try to delete something already deleted and end up with a heap corruption. I have try to set the m_bAutoDelete to TRUE and not delete the thread myself by I got the same crash (while the program was trying to call AfxEndThread).

The thread terminate its thread proc and return the exit code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like there is a problem here:

```
FileThread* FileThread::CreateWorkerThread(LPVOID params, UINT priority, 
                                           UINT flags)
{
    return (FileThread*) AfxBeginThread(FileThread::MyThreadProc, params, 
                                        priority, 0,  flags);
}
```

`AfxBeginThread` returns a `CWinthread*`, so just casting this to a derived class of your own does not make it an instance of that derived class. I'm surprised it works at all.

Rather than deriving `FileThread` from `CWinThread`, it might be better to hold a `CWinthread*` member variable inside your wrapper class and expose the thread handle via an accessor if necessary.

Comment: The following MSDN example shows how to do the casting properly
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2h4xz23.aspx

Also CWinthread has an automatic delete mechanism: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bbe9bte.aspx

Comment: @odedsh Well, sort of, that creates a UI thread which has a message pump (needed for sockets) - it *can* be used as a worker thread but it's possibly a bit of overkill in many situations.

Comment: @Roger Rowland: That's the kind of issue you think "OF COURSE MAN! AM I THAT STUPID?!" ;)
Thanks a lot I wrapped the CWinThread in my class and everything is OK.

Problem Solved